# PVANet parameters and MAC calculations

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I was going through a recent computationaly effiecent deep-learning architecte - PVANet:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.08021

I'm trying to understand how they got the #params,#MAC figures in Table 1 of the paper. For instance the number of computations for conv1_1 is 397M but I get:
(528*320)*16*3*49 = 660M
the formula I used - (image dim)*output channels*input channels*kernel size